# How to pass variables from Jade to Node.js endpoint function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I'm new to express and I want to pass the user.username from a jade file to the endpoint function in my javascript file.
This is the endpoint function in index.js:

```
router.get('/userdetail', function(req, res) {

   console.log(req.params)
   console.log(req.body)

   res.render('userdetail', { title: 'User Detail' });
});
```

This is my jade file:

```
extends layout
block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user, i in userlist
        li
            a(href="/userdetail/#{user.username}")= user.username
```

Basically, I'd like for the link to point to the user's page without needing to manually hardcode each user. If there's some way to do this in angularjs that would be fine too.

EDIT:
I edited my code as below but console.log() gave me undefined.

index.js:

```
router.get('/userdetail', function(req, res) {

   console.log(req.query.username);

   res.render('userdetail', { title: 'User Detail' });
});
```

userdetail.jade:

```
extends layout
block content
    h1.
        User List
    ul
        each user, i in userlist
            li
                a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username    
                a(href="/userdetail/?username = {user.username}")= user.username
```

Comment: You're passing `title` to your view (jade) but not `user`... you need to pass that along too. `req.query` should contain the GET params if I'm not mistaken, if `username=xxx` is not in the URL, then `req.query.username` is going to be undefined.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with _getting_ the username. :(

Comment: Well...where is it stored? Normally you'd have to query your database, pull out a list of users, and pass that to the view...

Answer (score 0):

You could set the username as a query parameter

```
a(href="/userdetail/?username={user.username}")= user.username
```

And access it in request.query ie request.query.username

Please note I might not have the correct jade syntax

Comment: The console.log() just gives me undefined. :(

Comment: Post your link I think my answer was wrong slightly.  The syntax shoud be a(href="/userdetail?username={user.username}")= user.username ie remove the last /

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the user object as an options argument to the res.render command.
Maybe something like this:

```
router.get('/userdetail', function(req, res) {

  locals = req.body.userlist

  res.render('userdetail', locals);

});
```

You just need to figure out how to retrieve the userlist from the request object and then pass it into the render options.

Comment: What I'm having trouble with is the "retrieving the user" part.

Comment: See @mpen's comment above